How to distribute VisualStyles in a C# WinForms project?
For my C# WinForms project, I created a self-contained package and it works. Problem is that I use  System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles to have dialogs in Vista style, but the style is not applied, the routine I use to show the Vista dialog return error (in which case I make the routine use the default dialogs, so no prompt is shown to the final user).
What should I distribute to make it work?
I also already included a manifest and the Application.EnableVisualStyles() method at the beginning of the Main() method.
Note that the software works as expected if executed from Debug folder or from the IDE itself, but not from the Release folder after the self-contained package is created.
I expect the Vista style dialogs to be displayed to the user in place of the standard common dialogs.

What version Net/Core?  You should use core and install the runtime version of Core that matches the version you used to build.  If you publish a core application the Runtime version of Core will automatically be installed when you run the setup.exe on the deploy machine.

This isn't likely the solution to your problem, but if you are using Net 6 or higher, you should use ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize(); instead of EnableVisualStyles or SetCompatibleRextRenderingDefault.  It does the same thing but it also sets Dpi Awareness.

@jdweng In Self-Contained builds, you don't distribute or download the runtime, you install the runtime components you are using along with the application. Silver Black, are you using dotnet publish or dotnet build? If you use publish it should assembly all of the necessary assemblies for distribution.  If you are using Visual Studio, right click your startup project and choose Publish (or from the Build menu, Publish Selection).

@Tarazed : You are basically agreeing with what I said.  With Core you do not need to publish if the Runtime version is already install on deploy machine.  All You need to do is to copy the executable(s).

@jdweng No, that is not describing a Self-Contained executable, that is describing a Framework-Dependent executable.  If the runtime is installed via the redistributable, either manually, by a custom installer, or by the bootstrapper that you described which prompts you to download it when you run it, that is Framework-Dependent.
When you publish self-contained, the output folder contains all the app needs, including the .NET library assemblies (this has advantages and disadvantages).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

My target framework is ".NET 8.0".
The weird thing is that if I run the executable from the "bin\Release\net8.0-windows\publish\self-contained" folder I have the glitch, while from the "bin\Debug\net8.0-windows" it runs ok, so also on the same development machine!

I also already use ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize(); and use Publish from Visual Studio by right-clicking on my project.
